# How to allocate compound objects from a pool in Google.Protobuf C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I'm using the Google.Protobuf 3.2.0 implementation in C#. I'm trying to make it allocate objects from a pool. The reason for doing this is that they need to be passed via a queue to another thread for processing, and I want my application to be [garbage-free in steady state running](https://github.com/real-logic/Aeron/wiki/Design-Principles#garbage-free-in-steady-state-running).

This is easy enough for a simple object.

E.g. with the following proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3"
message SimpleMessage {
    int32 number = 1;
}
```

I can implement a custom parser:

```
var parser = new MessageParser<SimpleMessage>(() => 
             {
                 // allocate from pool
                 return pool.GetObject();
             });
parser.ParseDelimitedFrom(stream)
```

It will call the delegate every time it needs a new object, so I can implement a pool.

But how do I do this for a compound object, with nested members?

```
syntax = "proto3"
message CompoundMessage {
    oneof Alternatives {
        SimpleMessage1 simple1 = 1;
        SimpleMessage2 simple2 = 2;
    }
}
```

I can create the top level custom parser for CompoundMessage, but how do I change the parser (or factory) it uses for creating nested objects?

Comment: This may or may not help you, but protobuf-net (different lib) allows a factory method to be set for any type(s) - the factory method currently needs to be a static method that can optionally take any combination of `SerializationContext`, `StreamingContext` (for conveying a shared state - ctx can be provided to the serialize/deserialize calls) and/or `Type` as parameters - and returns either `object` or an object of the expected type for that usage. The unreleased protobuf-net code extends this with a new fully external serializer method concept that allows full control of the reader etc.

Comment: Thanks Marc that sounds ideal. Unfortunately we recently ported our code from proto2 (with protobuf-net) to proto3 (with google.protobuf), as it didn't look like proto3 support was forthcoming on protobuf-net. In hindsight i should have checked this out first :-)

Comment: acknowledged; note I *do want* to add proto3 support, but ... demand has seemed low for it, and DSL tools have never been the strong suit of protobuf-net; my biggest concern, oddly, is trying to do it in a way that works fully cross-platform for .net core; the existing protogen executes `protoc`, which is hella awkward for x-plat. Would love to find some time to play with antlr or similar on .net core, to see what we can get working